# How to correct for inaccurate Javascript math with math.round()?

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I posted this code a couple days back, but the discussion seemed to wax philosophical about the weaknesses of Javascript (not to mention my own obvious weaknesses as a "programmer") and then died out without ever clarifying a solution. I'm hoping someone will help rectify that.

Due to a phenomenon apparently known as "floating point math," Javascript returns an arithmetically inaccurate answer (.00000004 or similar below the correct answer) in the calculator code below. I was advised to round the answer up by "calling math.round() on the variable," which I think would work fine for my purposes, only my JS kung fu was too weak, and the syntax of doing so in context has thus far eluded me.

Where/how to I make this call? So far all my attempts have failed, even when I thought for sure each would not. I would sure appreciate an answer that takes into account my low-level knowledge of the subject. This has got to be a slam-dunk for somebody out there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script language="javascript">

<!-- Begin Trip Tickets Savings Calc script
function  doMath4() {
    var one = parseInt(document.theForm4.elements[0].value);
    var two = parseInt(document.theForm4.elements[1].value);
    var selection = document.getElementsByName("zonett")[0].value;

    if(selection == "z4"){
        var prodZ4tt = (((one  *   two) * 4.25) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 3.75) *12);
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prodZ4tt  +  ".");
    }
    else if(selection == "z3"){
        var prodZ3tt = (((one  *   two) * 3.75) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 3.35) *12);
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prodZ3tt  +  ".");
    }
    else if(selection == "z2"){
        var prodZ2tt = (((one  *   two) * 3) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 2.8) *12);
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prodZ2tt  +  ".");
    }
    else if(selection == "z1"){
        var prodZ1tt = (((one  *   two) * 2.5) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 2.3) *12);
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prodZ1tt  +  ".");
    }
    else if(selection == "Base"){
        var prodBasett = (((one  *   two) * 1.5) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 1.5) *12);
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $"  +  prodBasett  +  ".");
    }
}

// End Trip Tickets Savings Calc script -->

</script>
</head>

<body>


<form name="theForm4" class="calcform">
<h2>You Do the Math: Commuter Express Trip Tickets Vs. Cash</h2>
<div class="calcform-content">
    <div class="formrow-calc">
      <div class="calcform-col1">
        <p>Days you commute on Commuter Express monthly:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="calcform-col2">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="calcform-col3">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>


    <div class="formrow-calc">
      <div class="calcform-col1">
        <p>Daily boardings on Commuter Express Bus:</p>

        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="fareexampletable">
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="savingsleft"><p class="ifyouride">EXAMPLE:</p></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="savingsleft"><p><strong>Go to work:</strong></p></td>
              <td class="savingsright"><p>1 time</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="savingsleft"><p><strong>Come home from work:</strong></p></td>
              <td class="additionline savingsright"><p>+1 time</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="savingsleft"><p><strong>Total:</strong></p></td>
              <td class="savingsright"><p>2 times</p></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
      <div class="calcform-col2">
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="calcform-col3">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>


    <div class="formrow-calc savings-zone">
      <div class="calcform-col1">
        <p>Choose Zone:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="calcform-col2">
        <select name="zonett">
          <option value="Base">Base</option>
          <option value="z1">Zone 1</option>
          <option value="z2">Zone 2</option>
          <option value="z3">Zone 3</option>
          <option value="z4">Zone 4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="formrow-calc">


          <div class="calcform-col4-ce">


 <button type="submit" onclick="doMath4()" class="btn-submit"><div class="btn-submit"><img src="img/btn_savings.png" alt="Show My Yearly Savings" /></div></button> 


    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">


</div>



</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you arriving at an inaccuracy?

Comment: @ 65Fbef05 Only when IO choose zones 1-3

Comment: The solution is simple: Don't use floating point values in financial computation. Use cents for everything or multiple accordingly so that you don't have to work with floating point numbers...

Comment: @Felix Say Huh? Simple, you say? I clearly am out of my element here, but I'm seeing cent values in those admittedly awkward but still functional formulae. The solution may be simple, but I still haven't seen it.

Comment: What I mean is that you should work on integers only and only for presentation create floating point values. So instead of `3.12 * 12` you have `312 * 1200` and for presentation you divide it by `100` again.

Comment: Holy cow, @Felix, that actually made sense to me. I just bloody well learned something here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a kludge with Math.round, but that will nuke cents (not sure if this applies in your example, it sort of looks like it could). What you may want is toFixed:

```
alert((102.000000004).toFixed(2)); // alerts "102.00"
```

This does NOT round in IE, but from what I can tell this will not matter in your case.

(docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed , http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=102421 , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sstyff0z.aspx )

Edit: intended to put this in the comments, but markdown doesn't work there? Still getting used to SO...

Anyhow, you can also use a kludge with Math.round if you prefer:

```
alert(Math.round(val * 100) / 100);
```

Which may still display the silly float issues, for which you could use another .toFixed (and now you're 100% sure there's no leftover decimal places you're not rounding properly):

```
alert((Math.round(val * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
```

Edit: to integrate:

Add this at the top of your script block:

```
function roundNicely(val) {
     return (Math.round(val * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}
```

Then in your alerts, wrap the value `prodBasett` in the function call: `roundNicely(prodBasett)` (and similar for the other alerts)

Does that make sense?

Comment: @Gijs, thanks, but unfortunately I do need cross browser compatibility (are you saying that IE actually computes the math correctly?), and I need to get the two decimal places in there.

Comment: @user: Have you checked the results in IE?

Comment: @Felix - on a mac at the moment, and my PC is currently indisposed. I'll be checking when that situation resolves.

Comment: From what I understand, it will work just fine in IE. It's just if you had, say: $240.005, it would end up being 240.00 instead of 240.01 as you would expect, in IE. However, looking at the numbers in your app, this doesn't matter. You only have numbers with 2 or fewer decimal places, and you're multiplying, so there won't be 3rd decimals (no valid ones, anyhow).

Comment: @Gijs I love kludges, and I'm fascinated by your answer, but how do I work that into my code syntactically? Is that the right word?

Comment: @user719431: Added this in my answer.

Comment: @Gijs By cracky, that appears to have done it. The kludge wins!

Answer (score 2):

In general **you want to round last**, so you maintain mathematical accuracy up until the point that data is displayed.

Here is how I would implement your little library:

```
var SavingsLib = {
    round : function(val, digits) {
        var pow = Math.pow(10, digits);
        return Math.round(pow * val) / pow;
    },

    padCurrency : function (val) {
        var str = val.toString();
        var parts = str.split(".");
        return parts.length > 1 && parts[1].length == 1 ? str + "0" : str;
    },

    processForm : function() {
        var daysPerMonth = parseInt(document.theForm4.elements[0].value);
        var boardingsPerDay = parseInt(document.theForm4.elements[1].value);
        var zone = document.getElementsByName("zonett")[0].value;

        var savings = 0;
        if(zone == "z4") savings = this.calculateSavings(daysPerMonth, boardingsPerDay, 4.25, 3.75);
        else if(zone == "z3") savings = this.calculateSavings(daysPerMonth, boardingsPerDay, 3.75, 3.35);
        else if(zone == "z2") savings = this.calculateSavings(daysPerMonth, boardingsPerDay, 3, 2.8);
        else if(zone == "z1") savings = this.calculateSavings(daysPerMonth, boardingsPerDay, 2.5, 2.3);
        else if(zone == "Base") savings = this.calculateSavings(daysPerMonth, boardingsPerDay, 1.5, 1.5);

        this.showMessage(savings);

        return false; // Don't submit form
    },

    calculateSavings : function(daysPerMonth, boardingsPerDay, price1, price2) {
        var amount1 = (((daysPerMonth * boardingsPerDay) * price1) * 12);
        var amount2 = (((daysPerMonth * boardingsPerDay) * price2) * 12);

        return this.round(amount1 - amount2, 2);
    },

    showMessage : function(savings) {
        alert("Your yearly savings if you buy Trip Tickets is $" + this.padCurrency(savings));
    }
}
```

My changes:

- Encapsulated functions into an object for namespacing
- Extracted the math out into a single method so **you can make one *round* call**
- Extracted the showing of the message into a method so you can modify it easily
- **Added a round-to-digits function** (So `1.4500001` becomes `1.45` instead of  `1`)
- Added a pad currency function (So `1.4` becomes `1.40`)

Comment: Thank you for the detail. Surely I implemented it incorrectly, because it did not work. Is this to replace the contents of the doMath4() function?  As in: function doMath4()    { ...your code here... }

Comment: No, actually, you want to call `SavingsLib.processForm();` from the button that you want to alert the savings value.

Answer (score 1):

It's [very simple](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp):

```
var prodZ4tt = Math.round(((one  *   two) * 4.25) *12) - (((one  *   two) * 3.75) *12);
```

Although it's understandable why you might get confused about syntax, since JavaScript is not known for its intuitive way of doing things. ;)

**Note:** This rounds the number to the nearest integer, it doesn't "round up."

Comment: Thanks, both for the answer and the empathy. One thing, how do we make this round to the nearest 2nd decimal (so that it displays dollars and cents)?

Answer (score 1):

For that cases when you need precision, you must need an Math "Arbitrary Precision Library"... you could find a good article here.

http://blog.thatscaptaintoyou.com/introducing-big-js-arbitrary-precision-math-for-javascript/

Javascript natively have round, ceil and floor to convert floats to integers.

```
var fl = 349.12783691847;
Math.round(fl) // 349
Math.ceil(f1) // 350
Math.floor(fl) // 349
```

when you do math operations, is good practice use distributivity, and properly use of parenthesis.

```
Math.round(((((a + b) * (c - d)) % e) * f));
```

Be careful with "NaN" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) and non Number types.

have a nice day